# Launcher not showing among other things

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I installed 12.10 on my HP Pavilion dm1. The Launcher does not appear. It is not hidden. I can't get into the hub either. There are no choices at the top of the screen either, once I log in. How can I get my Launcher back?

## Launcher